# Installing python package through AUR gives distutils error on ArchLinux

Tags: python, linux, archlinux, distutils

Hello I am running ArchLinux with latest version of Python(3.10+) and I am installing python packages. I require a dependency that I can't get through pacman so I am using AUR to get python-onnx package

When I run makepkg I get this error

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpjgzqj6vs', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

I am not really sure what is cause of this as I am not using pip but I do have it installed. Could someone please advise what this error message is referring to and potential fix?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was just missing the pytest-runner package which you can get

```
pacman -S python-pytest-runner
```

Usually it would tell you are missing a module/dependency. I am not sure why it caused the error to be thrown this way.